# Javascript Arrow Function

Tags: javascript

I am running both the code blocks in chrome tab console but I am not able to
understand why is the output of second block NaN.The values passed should in the second case doesn't include b, which should not matter is what I think.

```
var adder = {
  base: 1,

  add: function(a) {
    var f = v => v + this.base;
    return f(a);
  },

  addThruCall: function(a,n) {
    var f = (v,n) => v + n + this.base;
    var b = {
      base: 2
    };         
   return f.call(b,a,n);
  }
};
console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4)); // output: 8
```

But when I do

```
var adder = {
 base: 1,

 add: function(a) {
   var f = v => v + this.base;
   return f(a);
 },

 addThruCall: function(a,n) {
   var f = (v,n) => v + n + this.base;
   var b = {
     base: 2
   };         
   return f.call(a,n);
 }
};
console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4)); //output: NaN
```

Comment: The first argument of fn.call() is the 'this' argument. So `f.call(a, n)` is the same as calling `f( n, undefined )` with 'a' being `this` inside f. Hence you get NaN since number + undefined = NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` as first argument accepts value that will be used as `this` (called an `context`) in called function.  So in second example (`f.call(a,n)`) `a` is considred to be context argument and `n` is considered to be `f` function first argument - so as a result your `f` function is actually called with only single argument so the second argument is `undefined` - it's equivalent of calling `f(n)` but `f` function expects two arguments. As a result inside function you're adding number to `undefined` which gives you `NaN`.

*One more thing to clarify:*

since `this` is not bound in arrow functions when calling `call` method on arrow function first argument (context) is ignored and it will not be used as `this` value inside arrow function but in your second example it is not cause of your probem and even if you used normal function problem would still exist

Comment: Since this is not bound in arrow functions, this is ignored from the parameter. When I do console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4,5)) , it also return NaN. but it should have one 4 +5 +1 ie 10

Comment: No. When you call `f.call(a,n)` you actually do this: `f(n)` - `f` function is called with SINGLE argument so second argument is `undefined`. First argument of `call` method is not passed to called function as argument but as context. Please check `call` documentation to have full understading of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1):

In the second part of your code:

```
var adder = {
 base: 1,

 add: function(a) {
   var f = v => v + this.base;
   return f(a);
 },

 addThruCall: function(a,n) {
   var f = (v,n) => v + n + this.base;
   var b = {
     base: 2
   };         
   return f.call(a,n);
 }
};
console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4));
```

If you focus on the `console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4))`
it does:

```
return f.call(3, 4) // where 3 is the context specified and 4 is the argument
```

which means you called,

```
f(4, undefined) // called with 4
```

Not just that, you are returning:

```
v + n + this.base
```

so now,

```
4 + undefined + 1
```

That's `NaN`

---

For better visualisation use this:

```
addThruCall: function(a,n) {
 var f = (v,n) => {
   console.log(v, n, this.base)
   return v + n + this.base;
 }
 var b = {
   base: 2
 };         
 return f.call(a,n);
}
```

---

Solution:

```
addThruCall: function(a,n) {
  var f = (v=0,n=0) => v + n + this.base;

    var b = {
      base: 2
    };         
   return f.call(a,v,n);
  }
```

Comment: In that case If I do console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4,5));  It should return me a result but It returns NaN.

Comment: Because `f` didnt receive `n` as the argument. `f.call(a, n)` is the problem, it is not providing the 2nd argument to `f`. `f.call` would need 3 arguments to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I think I got it If I  keep
var adder = {
  base: 1,
    
  add: function(a) {
    var f = v => v + this.base;
    return f(a);
  },

  addThruCall: function(x,y) {
    var f = (v,n) => v + n + this.base;
    var b = {
      base: 2
    };         
    return f.call(x,y,2);
  }
};
console.log(adder.addThruCall(3,4,5));  //O/P 7

Comment: yes, `f.call` takes first argument as a replacement for the `this` keyword but that is not happening in your case as you are using an arrow function. So you need to pass three arguments if the original function needed 2.

Answer (score 0):

call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

Instead of using call, You can directly return f(a,n);

Comment: I wanted to understand the concept of call/apply.